# Are there some libraries with C API to draw pictures?

Tags: c, linux, graphics

Are there some libraries with C API to draw pictures? Just like the library `matplotlib` in python. I will use it to draw lines, dots, circles and I hope it has detailed documentation and opensource. My platform is gentoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most comprehensive one is probably [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). They suggest using the [MagickWand](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) API.

Other options are [cairo](http://cairographics.org/), with a image buffer output device, or maybe [libgd](https://github.com/libgd/libgd).

Answer (score 1):

There's no such functionality in the C standard library.

Comment: My question doesn't limit to standard library.

Comment: You said, and I quote, "Does C have some libraries to draw pictures?" C does not. Here's why. Per the C standard, the C language only includes the standard library and per that same standard the standard library doesn't have anything for drawing pictures. All other libraries are out of the scope of the language, although they can be implemented in it or for it. In other words, they may exist, but, unlike things like `printf()`, they aren't guaranteed to be available for every OS and every compiler.

Comment: And besides after 40 years, I would think they would have created a properitery library for this task. So a question should rather be, what API can I use with C for graphics?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your needs. Maybe you can use

- [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer)
- [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php) also has C bindings

These are game engines (full list of them [here](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Game_Engines) - check with C bindings), but you can also use them for drawing plots and etc too.
Also you can check - maybe you can include [Python bindings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509156/anyone-knows-a-matplotlib-equivalent-in-c-or-c), and after that - run Python code (matplotLib) from C ?

Answer (score 0):

One popular choice is [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). I'm not familiar with matplotlob, it's possible that SDL is (quite a bit) more low-level than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you running linux and compiling with gcc, the most obvious choice would be [plotutils](http://www.gnu.org/s/plotutils/). It has both a C and a C++ API.